# C++ references to JNI types such as jobject

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, interop

I am new to JNI, and I am confused by mixing JNI types such as jobject
and the regular C++ references and pointers. For example, I see this in a project
I work on:

```
Optimizer(jobject&);
```

It is constructor that takes a reference to jobject. Can you please help me understand
what does a reference to a jobject mean, and also what does a pointer to a jobject mean?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference to a `jobject` simply means that a pointer to the `jobject` reference has been passed to the constructor instead of an actual `jobject`.

Comment: a pointer to a jobject reference, ok this is getting confusing